# Form Input: Get Unique Value With Same Name & ID

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, mobile

Below is my result from my query which is posted to my address page. This is accomplished using php which is called with ajax.

```
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3719 COCOPLUM CIR <br>
Unit: 3548<br>
COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64638716">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3927 COCOPLUM CIR <br>
Unit: 35124<br>
COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64638744">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949A COCOPLUM CIR <br>
Unit: A<br>
COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639105">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949 COCOPLUM CIR <br>
Unit: 3602<br>
POMPANO BEACH, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639106">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949 COCOPLUM CIR <br>
Unit: 3603<br>
COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639107">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report">
</form>
```

Below is the request on my report page. I need to get the value from the form and pass it to my reports page so I can append my ajax request.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var property-id = $('.property-id').val();          
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/php/reports.php',
        data: '?recordID=' + property-id,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#results').html(data);

                }   
            }); 

               </script>
```

My main issue is that I don't get the value from the form I clicked on. It give me the first value in the list which 64638716. How can i get it to append the proper values

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.
There were few errors in your JavaScript, your variables names contained hyphen `property-id` but i changed that to `propertyid`, dont forget to modify that in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
        var propertyid = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val();
        //alert(propertyid);
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.domain.com/php/reports.php',
            data: '?recordID=' + propertyid,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }   
            }); 
        e.preventDefault()
        return false; // prevent form from submitting
    });    
});
```

Comment: Hey Francis, Ajax library is included. Second the unique value is my record ID, and is already setup and working. Problem is that each input has same ID, and class which is generated through a loop. So how would I pass that value to a new page without looping through all values (which is what it is doing).

Comment: You should show more code for preview, i this its going to help. or create a jsfiddle sample

Comment: @user2397810 try the code in my edited answer, also a working fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/9C2g5/ that alerts the textbox content.

Comment: Hey Francis, Thanks for the update. The code works if I keep it all on the same page. However, when my action is report.html it doesnt alert the code. I made sure to include the jquery lib. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2397810 do you mean the form action? The form action is already set to `report.html` can you update the code or create a fiddle.